# Is this a valid pdf

Tags: density-function

$f_x (x)= x$ if $x \in [0,1]$ and $f_x = 0$ otherwise. Is this a valid pdf? It seems to me it is not since the area under the pdf is 0.5.

Comment: What about multiplying it with $2$?

Comment: do you mean $f_x (x) = 2x$? If this is the case, then yes.

Comment: It seems you already answered your own question, if it doesn't have total probability 1 it's clearly not a valid pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply your function with $2$, then it will be a density:
$$ f(x)=2 x \cdot \mathcal{I}_{[0,1]}(x).  $$